# After converting string array into integer array, the function is returning a null array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

The function convertStringArray does not return the integer array after parsing string to integer array. 
    A null array is returned instead. The function should convert string to integer and return to readCodefile function. 
    The readCode file function return an integer array to the main function.
    Help needed.

```
package subsetsum;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class filehandling {

    String [] codes = new String[100000];
    int i = 0;

    private Scanner readCodes;

    public int[] readCodesFile() {
        try {
            readCodes = new Scanner(new File("uk.txt")); //Reading File
            codes[i] = readCodes.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(codes[i]);
            i++;
            while(readCodes.hasNext()) {
                codes[i] = readCodes.nextLine();
                //System.out.println(codes[i]);
                i++;
            }
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not locate the data file!");
        }

        int intCode1 [] = convertStringArray(codes);
        return intCode1;
    }

    public int[] readCodesFile1() {
        try {
            readCodes = new Scanner(new File("uk2`enter code here`.txt"));
            codes[i] = readCodes.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(codes[i]);
            i++;
            while(readCodes.hasNext()) {
                codes[i] = readCodes.nextLine();
                //System.out.println(codes[i]);
                i++;
            }
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not locate the data file!");
        }

        int intCode2 [] = convertStringArray(codes);
        return intCode2; // Here is where the error takes place
        }

    public int[] convertStringArray(String[] codes) {
        int[] intCodes = new int[codes.length];
        int count = 0;
        for (String string : codes) {
            intCodes[count] = Integer.parseInt(string);
            //System.out.println(intCodes[count]);
            count++;
        }
        //System.out.println(intCodes[i]);
        return intCodes;
    }
}
```

Comment: How it is possible `int intCode1 [] = convertStringArray(codes);`? Please, resolve compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is most likely to throw a `NumberFormatException`, since your `convertStringArray` method is passed a String array of `100000` Strings, so if you don't actually read 100000 Strings from the input file, some of the Strings in the `codes` array will remain `null`, and `parseInt` will fail to parse them.

You should probably use an ArrayList instead of an array to read the Strings from the file, unless you know the exact number of Strings you are going to find in the input file.

Comment: @user4699506 As I suggested, you can read the Strings into an `ArrayList<String>` instead of into a String array.

Answer (score 0):

The convertStringArray Method is probably not wrong. But you should not create the String Array with a large fixed size and iterate over it all. Try something like this:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static int[] convertStringArray(List<String> codes) {
      int[] intCodes = new int[codes.size()];
      int count = 0;
      for (String string : codes) {
          intCodes[count] = Integer.parseInt(string);
          count++;
      }
      return intCodes;
  }

  public static List<String> readStrings() {
      List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
      out.add("1");
      out.add("2");
      out.add("3");
      return out;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] intCodes = convertStringArray(readStrings());

      for (int intCode : intCodes) {
          System.out.println(intCode);
      }

  }
}
```